# How to mock a method in Service layer

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

While doing unit tests on each method of the service layer, I have encountered the below scenario, that I couldn’t figure out how to test:

```java
public class UserServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public void abc(){
        xyz(obj);
    }

    private void xyz(){
        userRepository.save(obj);
    }
}
```

What I want to test is the `abc()` method. Within that method, it invokes `xyz()` which is a **PRIVATE** method that uses the `userRepository` dependency. So, when I create a unit test for the `abc()` method, do I need to be concerned about the `xyz()` method since it is using a dependency? And if yes, what are the steps that I need to follow?

Comment: You'd need to instantiate `UserServiceImpl` with a mocked version of `UserRepository`.

Comment: Hi @slauth, I had the same idea. But is it okay to do so?

Comment: Sure… Why do you think it wouldn't be okay?

Comment: @NisalPubudu - please select/upvote an answer if you found any of them helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a void method, what you want to do is verify that the `save` method of the dependency has been called exactly once with the parameter `obj`. You could do this by using something like `Mockito`. Your unit test would look something like this:

```
    @Mock
    private UserRepository mockUserRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl sut;

    @Test
    public void abc_savesObject() {
        // Arrange
        ...

        // Act
        sut.abc();

        // Assert
        verify(mockUserRepository,times(1)).save(obj);
    }
```

Some useful links:

- https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4
- https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify

Comment: Hi @Ivan, if I follow above steps, will userRepository.save() method still persists data on actual database or not?

Comment: @NisalPubudu No data will be persisted as you are working with a mocked version of your repository. The @ Mock annotation creates a mock instance of your dependency. The @ InjectMocks annotation injects the mock instance as a dependency into the class you are unit testing, allowing you to verify how many times a method of the mock was invoked with particular parameters. It would be useful to read through the Mockito javadoc for more information: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote you need to deal with `xyz()` method and its call to `userRepository`. You need to mock `userRepository` as follows:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    public UserServiceImpl userService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Mock UserRepository behaviour
        doReturn(//return value).when(this.userRepository).save(any());
    }

    // Your tests here

}
```

Comment: @Nisal Pubudu did my answer help?

Comment: Yes @João, But I still don't have enough reps to upvote a answer. Once I have enough I'll upvote it. Thank you.